# Question regarding order relation of a Dedekind cut

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am currently studying mathematical logic and I have a question regarding a Dedekind cut.

My textbook defines a Dedekind cut, addition on the set of Dedekind cut and order relation on the set of Dedekind cut as follows:

**Def 1.** A Dedekind cut $\alpha$ is a set of rational number having following properties:

a) $\alpha \neq \mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha \neq \emptyset $

b) $p \in\alpha, q<p \implies q \in \alpha$

c) $\forall p \in \alpha, \exists q\in \alpha$ such that $q>p$

**Def 2.** $\alpha +\beta :=\{s+t \in \mathbb{Q} : s\in\alpha, t\in \beta \}$

**Def 3.** $\alpha \le\beta \iff \alpha \subseteq\beta$

I want to prove

If $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are Dedekind cut, and $\alpha+\gamma \le \beta+ \gamma$, then $\alpha \le \beta$

without mentioning additive inverse of $\gamma$ and using only those three definitions.

I proved for the strict inequality.

**proof** Assume that $\alpha +\gamma \neq \beta +\gamma$.  BWOC, suppose that

$\forall b \in \beta, \exists a\in \alpha$ s.t. $b<a \quad (1)$

Let $x \in \beta +\gamma$,then there exist $b \in \beta,c \in \gamma $ such that $x = b+c$. By (1) we can choose $a\in \alpha$ so that $x = b+c < a+c \in \alpha + \gamma$. By Def 1 (b), $x \in \alpha +\gamma$. Hence $\beta +\gamma \subset \alpha+\gamma$. But this is contradictory to $\alpha+\gamma \neq \beta + \gamma$ since $\alpha +\gamma\le \beta +\gamma$. Therefore $\alpha$ has upper bound in $\beta$ and this implies $\alpha \subseteq \beta$. $\blacksquare$

But I can't show when $\alpha+\gamma = \beta+\gamma$. Is it possible to prove without mentioning additive inverse of $\gamma$ ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires you to use some special properties of the rational numbers (besides just that they are an ordered abelian group); in other words, you can't prove this by just "formal" algebraic manipulations.

Here's the idea.  Suppose $a\in\alpha$.  By part (c) of Definition 1, there is $a'\in\alpha$ such that $a<a'$.  We know that for any $c\in\gamma$, $a'+c\in \alpha+\gamma\subseteq\beta+\gamma$, so we can write $a'+c=b+c'$ for some $b\in\beta$ and $c'\in\gamma$.  The idea is now to pick $c$ that is so close to the "end" of $\gamma$ that $a'+c=b+c'$ would force $b$ to be greater than $a$, so that $a\in\beta$.  In particular, if $a'=a+\epsilon$, then if $c$ is less than $\epsilon$ from the "end" of $\gamma$ then $c'<c+\epsilon$ so $a'+c=b+c'$ would force $b>a'-\epsilon=a$.

So to make this rigorous, what we need to know is that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $c\in\gamma$ such that for all $c'\in\gamma$, $c'<c+\epsilon$.  This requires using something special about rational numbers.  More details on how to prove it are hidden below.

> Since $\gamma\not=\emptyset,\mathbb{Q}$, we can pick $p\in\gamma$ and $q\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\gamma$.  Now we use something special about $\mathbb{Q}$: there exists a natural number $n$ such that $\dfrac{q-p}{\epsilon}\leq n$.  Consider the finite sequence $p,p+\epsilon,p+2\epsilon,\dots,p+n\epsilon$.  Since $p+n\epsilon\geq q$, the first term of this sequence is in $\gamma$ but the last term is not.  So take the last $m\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ such that $p+m\epsilon\in\gamma$, so $p+(m+1)\epsilon\not\in\gamma$.  Then $c=p+m\gamma$ is an element of $\gamma$ such that $c+\epsilon\not\in\gamma$, so every $c'\in\gamma$ must satisfy $c'<c+\epsilon$.